# How to access another FirebaseUser`s properties?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Well, I can access current `FirebaseUser` object as `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` and then I can call `getPhotoUrl()` or `getDisplayName()` methods.
The question is given user UUID, how can access another user's object and call these methods?

PS: on android

Comment: That would be called a security breach... doubt you will make that happen.

Comment: @theblindprophet so should I make my own JSON tree to keep those info and share it properly between users huh? Wasn't that be redundancy to keep same info twice?

Comment: If you want others users to have access to the info then yes, create your own subtree with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to do this is to store the shareable information about a user in the Firebase Database.

The documentation on firebase.com had a nice example for this. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing The approach is still the same with the new Firebase changes, although you'll need to massage the code a bit.

I'll add a note that we need to add a sample of this to the new Firebase documentation too.

Answer (score 1):

A FirebaseUser has a fixed set of basic properties—a unique ID, a primary email address, a name and a photo URL—stored in a separate project's user database; those properties can be updated by the user. You cannot add other properties to the FirebaseUser object directly; instead, you can store the additional properties in your Firebase Realtime Database.

```
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("email@example.com", "my pass")
    .continueWithTask(new Continuation<AuthResult, Task<Void>> {
        @Override
        public Task<Void> then(Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                DatabaseReference firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                return firebaseRef.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("phone").setValue("650-253-0000");
            } else {
                // User creation didn't succeed. Look at the task exception
                // to figure out what went wrong
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```